# Are targets aware when you mind probe them if they don't make their saves?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

So, [*mind probe*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/m/mind-probe)'s description says that you ask questions telepathically, but I was wondering if the targets are aware that they are being questioned if they don't make their save?

It would seem to me that they aren't aware since you can probe them even when they're sleeping, and they don't wake up until they make their save.

I just want some confirmation on if my suspicion is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes and No

> *Succeeding on a Saving Throw: A creature that successfully saves against a spell that has no obvious physical effects feels a hostile force or a tingle, but cannot deduce the exact nature of the attack. Likewise, if a creature's saving throw succeeds against a targeted spell, you sense that the spell has failed. You do not sense when creatures succeed on saves against effect and area spells.*

Going by this, unless they make a save, they are not aware.  This is the only rules text I could find regarding awareness of spells being cast on you, other than by making psicraft/spellcraft checks when observing something be manifested.

That said, it would probably call for a Sense Motive check on their behalf if you failed to suppress the [Auditory], [Visual], and [Material] display, and if they have and make a Psicraft check to know what you're manifesting, then you probably don't even get a bluff.  'He's casting mind probe and something just tried to invade my mind' is pretty self-explanatory.

Sources;

1. [Does a caster know a charm person failed?; paizo.com/forums; rules questions](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2n2w0?Does-a-caster-know-a-charm-person-failed)
2. [PFSRD 'Magic' chapter, subheading 'Succeeding on a Saving Throw'](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Saving-Throw)

Comment: @KRyan - This is a simple, low-key answer with all relevant rules quoted in the actual answer.  If you feel it's insufficient, then write a bigger one.